# Numpy.broadcast_to ValueError with big shapes

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a 5 dimension [sparse.COO](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/0.3.0/generated/sparse.COO.html#sparse.COO) named "other" with dimensions: (6318, 35, 1, 1, 17806)
on which I'm applying other.broadcast_to(tuple(broadcast_shape)) where broadcast_shape is an ndarray of type numpy.uint64 with the value [ 6318    35    36    21 17806]:

```
other_5dims = other.broadcast_to(tuple(broadcast_shape))
```

When I run the script, I get a `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4308114384,) into shape (13147088,)`

The original shape of "other" is `6318*35*1*1*17806 = 3,937,440,780`, which is smaller than `4,308,114,384` and I don't even know how the shape `(6318,35,36,21,17806)` generated the number `13147088` that is seen in the error message.

Why does it give me a value error, and what are these numbers from the error?

Edit: Closed this issue in GitHub repository of Sparse: [Closed Issue](https://github.com/pydata/sparse/issues/546)

Comment: `scipy.sparse.coo` is limited to 2 dimensions, so I'm lost as of the first step here.

Comment: scipy sparse matrices don't broadcast.  They are not a `ndarray` subclass.

Comment: @DanielF I'm not using scipy.sparse exactly for this reason. I'm using COO class from the package Sparse. here is the link: [link](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/0.3.0/install.html)

Comment: Something weird is likely happening on the backend data likely.  `4308114384-13147088 = 4294967296 == 2**32`, which implies to me that there's some intermediate step that's taking 32-bit blocks of data that's not working correctly in `sparse`.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks! so, how can I resolve it? I'm currently working on diving to the backend and finding the problem, but I don't know how to identify it

Comment: Digging into the `c` code backend is beyond my capabilities, sorry.

Comment: @DanielF Thank you for the answers. I'll try posting an issue to the package's GitHub repository

Comment: Try `other.coords = other.coords.astype(np.int64)` before you broadcast.

Comment: @CJR the dtype of other.coords is already int64

Answer (score 0):

I created a data structure so big that it's indices needed more than 32 bits, so I'll try to implement the data structure with less space.
You can read more info [here](https://github.com/pydata/sparse/issues/546)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).